# AttributeError: 'Operation' object has no attribute '_graph' in tf.keras.models.save_model()

Tags: tensorflow

I have what would appear to be a pretty straightforward model fitting process in a Jupyter notebook:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  feature_layer,
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(7, activation='softmax')
])
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adamax(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(train_ds, validation_data=val_ds,
          epochs=1, callbacks=[tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='accuracy', patience=10)])
```

When fitting is complete, I call `tf.keras.models.save_model(model)` (I have also tried `model.save(path)`), which saves successfully only if the notebook kernel has been loaded from scratch, otherwise it fails. For example if I run:

```
tf.keras.backend.clear_session()
tf.compat.v1.reset_default_graph()
del(model)
```

And try to execute the first block of code again, without reseting the kernel, I will get:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-d8fda83a42df> in <module>
----> 1 model.save('test3')

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/network.py in save(self, filepath, overwrite, include_optimizer, save_format, signatures, options)
   1006     """
   1007     save.save_model(self, filepath, overwrite, include_optimizer, save_format,
-> 1008                     signatures, options)
   1009 
   1010   def save_weights(self, filepath, overwrite=True, save_format=None):

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/saving/save.py in save_model(model, filepath, overwrite, include_optimizer, save_format, signatures, options)
    113   else:
    114     saved_model_save.save(model, filepath, overwrite, include_optimizer,
--> 115                           signatures, options)
    116 
    117 

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/saving/saved_model/save.py in save(model, filepath, overwrite, include_optimizer, signatures, options)
     76     # we use the default replica context here.
     77     with distribution_strategy_context._get_default_replica_context():  # pylint: disable=protected-access
---> 78       save_lib.save(model, filepath, signatures, options)
     79 
     80   if not include_optimizer:

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/saved_model/save.py in save(obj, export_dir, signatures, options)
    897   # Note we run this twice since, while constructing the view the first time
    898   # there can be side effects of creating variables.
--> 899   _ = _SaveableView(checkpoint_graph_view)
    900   saveable_view = _SaveableView(checkpoint_graph_view)
    901 

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/saved_model/save.py in __init__(self, checkpoint_view)
    185           #  variables on first run.
    186           concrete_functions = (
--> 187               function._list_all_concrete_functions_for_serialization())  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    188         else:
    189           concrete_functions = [function]

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/def_function.py in _list_all_concrete_functions_for_serialization(self)
    797     """
    798     if self.input_signature is not None:
--> 799       self.get_concrete_function()
    800     concrete_functions = []
    801     # pylint: disable=protected-access

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/def_function.py in get_concrete_function(self, *args, **kwargs)
    907       if self._stateful_fn is None:
    908         initializers = []
--> 909         self._initialize(args, kwargs, add_initializers_to=initializers)
    910         self._initialize_uninitialized_variables(initializers)
    911 

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/def_function.py in _initialize(self, args, kwds, add_initializers_to)
    495     self._concrete_stateful_fn = (
    496         self._stateful_fn._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
--> 497             *args, **kwds))
    498 
    499     def invalid_creator_scope(*unused_args, **unused_kwds):

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(self, *args, **kwargs)
   2387       args, kwargs = None, None
   2388     with self._lock:
-> 2389       graph_function, _, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
   2390     return graph_function
   2391 

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py in _maybe_define_function(self, args, kwargs)
   2701 
   2702       self._function_cache.missed.add(call_context_key)
-> 2703       graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
   2704       self._function_cache.primary[cache_key] = graph_function
   2705       return graph_function, args, kwargs

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py in _create_graph_function(self, args, kwargs, override_flat_arg_shapes)
   2591             arg_names=arg_names,
   2592             override_flat_arg_shapes=override_flat_arg_shapes,
-> 2593             capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),
   2594         self._function_attributes,
   2595         # Tell the ConcreteFunction to clean up its graph once it goes out of

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/func_graph.py in func_graph_from_py_func(name, python_func, args, kwargs, signature, func_graph, autograph, autograph_options, add_control_dependencies, arg_names, op_return_value, collections, capture_by_value, override_flat_arg_shapes)
    976                                           converted_func)
    977 
--> 978       func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
    979 
    980       # invariant: `func_outputs` contains only Tensors, CompositeTensors,

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/def_function.py in wrapped_fn(*args, **kwds)
    437         # __wrapped__ allows AutoGraph to swap in a converted function. We give
    438         # the function a weak reference to itself to avoid a reference cycle.
--> 439         return weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
    440     weak_wrapped_fn = weakref.ref(wrapped_fn)
    441 

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/training/tracking/tracking.py in _initializer()
    242     @def_function.function(input_signature=[], autograph=False)
    243     def _initializer():
--> 244       self._initialize()
    245       return 1  # Dummy return
    246 

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/lookup_ops.py in _initialize(self)
    179 
    180   def _initialize(self):
--> 181     return self._initializer.initialize(self)
    182 
    183   @property

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/lookup_ops.py in initialize(self, table)
    462         self._name, values=(table.resource_handle, self._keys, self._values)):
    463       init_op = gen_lookup_ops.lookup_table_import_v2(table.resource_handle,
--> 464                                                       self._keys, self._values)
    465     ops.add_to_collection(ops.GraphKeys.TABLE_INITIALIZERS, init_op)
    466     return init_op

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/gen_lookup_ops.py in lookup_table_import_v2(table_handle, keys, values, name)
    700   _, _, _op, _outputs = _op_def_library._apply_op_helper(
    701         "LookupTableImportV2", table_handle=table_handle, keys=keys,
--> 702                                values=values, name=name)
    703   return _op
    704 LookupTableImportV2 = tf_export("raw_ops.LookupTableImportV2")(_ops.to_raw_op(lookup_table_import_v2))

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/op_def_library.py in _apply_op_helper(op_type_name, name, **keywords)
    740       op = g._create_op_internal(op_type_name, inputs, dtypes=None,
    741                                  name=scope, input_types=input_types,
--> 742                                  attrs=attr_protos, op_def=op_def)
    743 
    744     # `outputs` is returned as a separate return value so that the output

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/func_graph.py in _create_op_internal(self, op_type, inputs, dtypes, input_types, name, attrs, op_def, compute_device)
    589       if ctxt is not None and hasattr(ctxt, "AddValue"):
    590         inp = ctxt.AddValue(inp)
--> 591       inp = self.capture(inp)
    592       inputs[i] = inp
    593     return super(FuncGraph, self)._create_op_internal(  # pylint: disable=protected-access

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/func_graph.py in capture(self, tensor, name, shape)
    628       # Large EagerTensors and resources are captured with Placeholder ops
    629       return self._capture_helper(tensor, name, shape)
--> 630     if tensor.graph is not self:
    631       if name is None:
    632         name = tensor.op.name

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py in graph(self)
    414   def graph(self):
    415     """The `Graph` that contains this tensor."""
--> 416     return self._op.graph
    417 
    418   @property

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py in graph(self)
   2223   def graph(self):
   2224     """The `Graph` that contains this operation."""
-> 2225     return self._graph
   2226 
   2227   @property

AttributeError: 'Operation' object has no attribute '_graph'
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, I am experiencing a very similar issue. Any updates on a possible solution?

Comment: Can confirm with an anaconda tf.2.1 env

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have recreated your code and successfully ran it without any errors. Kindly use the latest **stable release** of **TensorFlow** in this case **2.1.0**.

If the problem still persists, try **updating** your **Jupyter Notebook**, **Python** (to the latest supported version), and or try **simulating it** first in **Google Colab** to ensure that this is not related to any hardware issues.

Screenshot of Successful execution:
[image: screenshot in google colab]

Here is my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
print('TensorFlow Version: {}'.format(tf.__version__))
# Synthetic Data
x, y =  tf.random.uniform(shape=(1000, 7, 1), maxval = 1), tf.random.uniform(shape=(1000, 7,1), maxval =1)

# Model
feature_layer = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape = (7,1))

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  feature_layer,
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu', input_shape = (7,1)),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(7, activation='softmax')
])
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adamax())
model.fit(x, y, epochs=1)

# 1st Save
first_model_loc = '/tmp/tf_keras_1st_run/'
tf.keras.models.save_model(model, filepath= first_model_loc)
print('\nSuccessfully saved at {}\n\n'.format(first_model_loc)) # Progress Checking

# 
tf.keras.backend.clear_session()
tf.compat.v1.reset_default_graph()
del(model)
#

# Model
feature_layer = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape = (7,1))

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  feature_layer,
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu', input_shape = (7,1)),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(7, activation='softmax')
])
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adamax())
model.fit(x, y, epochs=1)


# 2nd Save
second_model_loc = '/tmp/tf_keras_2nd_run/'
tf.keras.models.save_model(model, filepath=second_model_loc)
print('\nSuccessfully saved at {}'.format(second_model_loc)) # Progress Checking
```